# Coding a shape with CSS

Tags: css, shapes, alignment

I've created a shape purely by CSS. The following link includes my work.

http://jsfiddle.net/kaHek/119/

CSS:

```
#applicationStatus {
position: relative;
width: 630px;
height: 140px;
top: 20px;
left: 40px; }

ul.applicationStatus {
list-style: none; }

li.applicationStatus, li.applicationStatusGood, li.applicationStatusNoGood {
height: 140px;
background-color: #767676;
display: inline-block;
/* Dirty IE Hack */
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
margin-right: 30px;
padding: 10px;
color: white;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 150px;
/*      vertical-align: middle; */ }
li.applicationStatus:after, li.applicationStatusGood:after, li.applicationStatusNoGood:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 80px solid transparent;
border-left: 30px solid #77a942;
border-bottom: 80px solid transparent;
margin: -10px 90px 0 0px; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="applicationStatus">
    <ul>
        <li class="applicationStatus">Başvuru Alındı</li>
        <li class="applicationStatusGood">Dil Sınavı</li>
        <li class="applicationStatusNoGood">Sözlü Mülakat</li>
        <li class="applicationStatus">Hibe</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

[image]

I'm struggling with aligning the arrow part of the image. I created that part with *:after* pseudo-element with the help of [css3shapes.com](http://css3shapes.com) but I can't seem to align it properly.

Setting the margin value of the after selector works for vertical positioning but not for horizontal positioning.

What should I do?

Comment: yo must have a constant width.

Comment: @Can surmeli check the below solution..i hope this is what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/kaHek/120/

```
margin: -10px 90px 0 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Margin Rules:

```
Margin: 25px 50px 75px 100px;
```

- top margin is 25px
- right margin is 50px
- bottom margin is 75px
- left margin is 100px

---

In your case, this works fine: `margin: -10px 90px 0px 10px;`

Make sure that last value of this should equal with your `padding: 10px;` in `li.applicationStatus, li.applicationStatusGood, li.applicationStatusNoGood` method.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do this:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Chaq/)

Relavant code:

```
li {
    position:relative;
}

li:after {
    right:-30px; /* width of element */
    top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code you can achieve exactly what you are seeking for...! :)

[image: Desigred CSS3 Shape]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZxWE/1/)

Code:

HTML:

```
<div id="css3">
    <ul>
        <li class="css3">HTML5/CSS3</li>
        <li class="css3">Shapes</li>
        <li class="css3">Hello World!</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#css3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 630px;
  height: 140px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 40px;
}

ul.css3 {
  list-style: none;
}

li.css3 {
  height: 140px;
  background-color: #76a942;
  display: inline-block;
  /* Dirty IE Hack */
  zoom: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  }

li.css3:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 40px solid #76a942;
    border-top: 80px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 80px solid transparent;
    margin: -10px 90px 0 10px;
}
```